# how to implement the Working Hours Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

We want to limit the JENKINS execution only to working hours. For example daily we want to run the jenkins from 8am to 6pm. Everyday evening jenkins has to stop and resume in the morning automatically. We are using this  **Working Hours Jenkins Plugin** to achieve this requirement. When I configured the same under the system configuration, it didn't work the way expected. We are using Jenkins GUI to schedule the jobs. Please find the attached screenshot of my Working Hours Jenkins Plugin schedule. What am I missing here? Would you please help me to go through this? I appreciate any help you can provide.

[Working Hours Jenkins Plugin-Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2d82.png)

Comment: Did you configure the relevant jobs to use this plugin?

Comment: @NoamHelmer : No I didn't configure to individual jobs. Could you please let me know how to do that? Thanks

Comment: added the explanation as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Detailed information on the plugin usage is available on the Plugin [Github Page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/working-hours-plugin).

> The working hours plugin allows you to set up a schedule of allowable build times; projects can opt in to use the schedule to prevent them from running outside of configured allowable build times. If a build is scheduled during non-working hours then it is kept in the build queue until the next allowable time.
> Jobs opt in via the `enforceBuildSchedule` job parameter, which is provided by this plugin. It can optionally take in a branches parameter to limit it's usage to only those branches. This only works in MultiBranchPipelines.

So to use the plugin you need to configure your requested schedule (like you did) in the *Configure System* menu - that will hold the general configuration for this plugin but it will not affect any job yet:

> In order to use the working hours plugin, you must set up a schedule in your Jenkins system configuration page. The following configuration will cause jobs with `enforceBuildSchedule` to queue if ran outside of Monday - Friday 8:00 AM to 6:00 PM.

This means that in order to affect a job (currently only pipeline jobs are supported - not freestyle) you must explicitly configure that job to enforce the configured schedule. This enforcement is done using the `enforceBuildSchedule` keyword provided by the plugin.
For scripted pipelines it will look like:

```groovy
node {
   properties([enforceBuildSchedule()])
   stage('Do some stuff') {
      echo 'this can wait til morning'
   }
}
```

For declarative pipelines it will look like:

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any
   options {
       enforceBuildSchedule()
   }
   stages {
       stage('Do some stuff') {
           steps {
               echo 'this can wait til morning'
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And that is it, you must configure each relevant job to use the schedule or else it wont be affected from it at all.